# bashrc function for firewall-cmd --add-service

Tags: bash, alias

How can I create an alias function called `fadd()` in bashrc, which will take a service name as a parameter and execute `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=$argument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really have "alias functions" as aliases are explicitly not functions; they just do this (from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases)):

> The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked to see if it has an alias. If so, that word is replaced by the text of the alias.

Without ugly hacks, it's not possible to use arguments for aliases. To define a function, you can add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
fadd () {
    firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service="$1"
}
```

and then call it with `fadd service`, for any `service` you want.

Comment: I'am getting an error while sourcing the new bashrc "syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @Rousseau You have probably still set it as an alias. Test with `alias fadd`, and if it shows up, unalias it with `unalias fadd`.